# Low performace(?) with 200 moving circles in Starling

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I have this code that draws a rain like animation with 200 circle shapes.
Basically 200 circle shapes with random x, y, radius and speed that go from top to bottom, and resets back to the top at random x (again) when it exists the screen... on LG G2 I get 26FPS with 200 circles, and I suspect I'm doing something wrong, since I know Starling can do MUCH better than this...

Main:

```
[SWF(width="640", height="960", frameRate="60", backgroundColor="#ffffff")]
public class ParticleTest extends Sprite
{
    private var _starling:Starling;

    public function ParticleTest()
    {
        var screenWidth:int  = stage.fullScreenWidth;
        var screenHeight:int = stage.fullScreenHeight;
        var viewPort:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)

        _starling = new Starling(Particle, stage, viewPort);
        _starling.stage.stageWidth  = 640;
        _starling.stage.stageHeight = 960;
        _starling.showStats = true;
        _starling.start();
    }
}
```

Particle:

```
private var particles:Array = [];

    public function Particle()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(event:Event):void {
        for (var i:int=0;i<200;i++) {
            particles[i] = new Circle();
            addChild(particles[i]);
        }

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
    }

    private function update(event:Event):void {
        for (var i:int=0;i<particles.length;i++) {
            particles[i].update();
        }
    }
```

Circle:

```
private var _x:int = 0;
    private var _y:int = 0;
    private var _speed:int = 0;
    private var _radius:int = 0;
    private var _color:uint = 0x000000;

    private var MIN_RADIUS:int = 2;
    private var MAX_RADIUS:int = 14;
    private var MIN_SPEED:int = 8;
    private var MAX_SPEED:int = 14;
    private var COLORS:Array = [0xff7729, 0x1ab58a, 0xffebca, 0xff2151, 0xffad29];

    private var _shape:Shape = new Shape();
    private var _graphics:Graphics = _shape.graphics;
    private var _bmpData:BitmapData;
    private var _image:Image;

    public function Circle()
    {
        shuffle();
        init();
        draw();
    }

    private function shuffle():void {
        this._radius = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.MAX_RADIUS) + this.MIN_RADIUS;
        this._color = this.COLORS[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.COLORS.length)];
        this._speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.MAX_SPEED) + this.MIN_SPEED;
        this._x = Math.floor(Math.random() * Starling.current.nativeStage.stageWidth);
        this._y = Math.floor(Math.random() * Starling.current.nativeStage.stageHeight) - Starling.current.nativeStage.stageHeight;
    }

    private function init():void {
        this._graphics.clear();
        this._graphics.beginFill(this._color, 1);
        this._graphics.drawCircle(this._radius, this._radius, this._radius);
        this._graphics.endFill();

        this._bmpData = new BitmapData(this._radius*2, this._radius*2, true, 0x000000);
        this._bmpData.draw(this._shape);

        this._image = Image.fromBitmap(new Bitmap(this._bmpData, "auto", true));
        addChild(this._image);
    }

    private function draw():void {
        this._image.x = this._x;
        this._image.y = this._y;        
    }

    public function update():void {
        this._image.x = this._x;
        this._image.y += this._speed;
        if (this._image.y > Starling.current.nativeStage.stageHeight) {
            shuffle();
            draw();
        }
    }
```

Am I doing it wrong? Is there a better way to achieve the same effect?

Thanks!

Comment: You create an unique bitmapData for each circle which means you force Starling to draw 200 times before rendering which is way too much.

Comment: BotMaster is right. Each new BitmapData required draw call. Also I recommend you to read Starling's article about optimization - http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/performance_optimization

Comment: Thank you both, but I guess I'm still missing something (even after reading the optimization page)... I assume there is a way of reusing one bitmapData, or alternatively make it draw all 200 circles at the same time, but I couldn't think of a way of doing this...

Any chance for a hint or a direction?

Comment: Think about passing in a single `BitmapData` to all your `Circle` objects.  Then see about using a single Graphics object to do all the drawing - you'll improve performance a lot if you can avoid all those `addChild()` calls.

Comment: That last advice is irrelevant since you would still end up with 200 draw calls. What you need is only one Image.fromBitmap for all your circle, use white color, then alter that color with the tint property of Starling object. You should end up with only one draw call for as many circle as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not copy and paste old code from classic AS3 to Starling you need use a new logic to optimize and exploit the advantages

```
  private var particles:Array = [];
  private var speeds:Array = [];

 private var MAX_SPEED = 10;
 private var MIN_SPEED = 1;

private var filter0:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter();
private var filter1:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter();
private var filter2:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter();
private var filter3:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter();
private var filter4:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter();
private var COLORS:Array = [filter0, filter1, filter2, filter3, filter4];


 // Embed the texture:
 [Embed(source="circle.png")]    //<---- EMBED A CRICLE PNG
  public static const Circle:Class;

public function Particle()
{
    addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}

var texture:Texture = Texture.fromBitmap(new Circle());
private function init(event:Event):void {
    filterRed.tint(0xff7729, 1);
    filterRed.tint(0x1ab58a, 1);
    filterRed.tint(0xffebca, 1);
    filterRed.tint(0xff2151, 1);
    filterRed.tint(0xffad29, 1);

    for (var i:int=0;i<200;i++) {
        particles[i] = new Image(texture);

        shuffle(i);


        addChild(particles[i]);
    }

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
}

private function update(event:Event):void {
    for (var i:int=0;i<particles.length;i++) {
        update(i);
    }
}

public function update(imageID:int):void {
    particles[imageID].x = x;
    particles[imageID].y += speeds[imageID];
    if (_image.y > Starling.current.nativeStage.stageHeight) {
        shuffle(i);
    }
}

public function shuffle(i:int):void {
    particles[i].scaleX = particles[i].scaleY = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.MAX_RADIUS/particles[i].width) + this.MIN_RADIUS/particles[i].width;
    particles[i].filter = this.COLORS[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.COLORS.length)];
    speeds[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.MAX_SPEED) + this.MIN_SPEED;
    particles[i]._x = Math.floor(Math.random() * Starling.current.nativeStage.stageWidth);
    particles[i]._y = Math.floor(Math.random() * Starling.current.nativeStage.stageHeight) - Starling.current.nativeStage.stageHeight;
}
```